# algorithm for grouping elements from multi dimensional matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, grouping

[image]

Hi fellows

I have a question in regards to an algorithm problem I am trying to solve.

The input data to the algorithm is a matrix that can be described as follows:

- The matrix has N dimensions, like the one in the attached picture (which has 2 dimensions for example).
- There are a number of elements (denoted as c1, .. c5 in the attached sample matrix) that are mapped into the cells of the matrix.
- An element can occur in one or more cells in the matrix.

The algorithm should work as follows:

Pick (and then remove) elements from the matrix and group them into buckets of E elements, so that:

- the elements in each bucket don't have any common values on any of the dimensions
- each element is assigned only into one bucket

For example, referring to the sample matrix attached, if we selected E to be 2, then a possible grouping could be: {c1, c2} ; {c3, c4} and {5} by itself. Check: c1 and c2 (and c3 and c4) don't have any common column or row values in the matrix.

The problem has been doing my head in for some time now and I thought it may be worth asking if some whiz here has a solution.

Thanks